# access the structure EVP_KEY thanks to a function

Tags: c++, openssl, cryptography

I am looking to display the content of the pointed variable "`ppkey`" which is in the structure `EVP_PKEY`.
Is there an openssl function capable of doing this?
If yes which?
here is my code:

```
EVP_PKEY *ppkey = NULL;
     if (1 != EVP_PKEY_keygen(ctx, &ppkey))
     {
        std::cout << "error 2" << std::endl;
     }
     else
     {
           std::cout << *ppkey << std::endl;
     }
```

Comment: what I understood is that this function converts a structure into an exadecimal or an octect.   because I am looking for a function that can allow me to display the content of this structure: EVP_PKEY * ppkey

Comment: I assume that by "exadecimal" you actually meant "hexadecimal".

Comment: I changed my main question to a more direct question of my problem.
I hope to be more understandable

Comment: no one has found an answer to my question? i really need help please

Comment: Why do you need to access the ameth? This is really an internal implementation detail not intended for direct access.

Comment: "ameth" is an example, my goal is to display the content of the pointer "* ppkey".

Comment: no one has an answer please?

Comment: The internal structure of EVP_PKEY is implementation dependent and likely of not much help. There are methods like EVP_PKEY_get_attr_count and EVP_PKEY_get_attr that could get you the attributes. But I don't think that everything is reachable this way. You might also download OpenSSL and include its source into your build, so you can examine the content with a debugger or include the internal headers for the actual content. But I strongly recommend against this except for learning OpenSSL's internals.